# finding the count in two lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, foreach, count

I have two lists which I am getting from database as follow:

```
List<myobject1> frstList = ClientManager.Get_FirstList( PostCode.Text, PhoneNumber.Text);
                List<myobject2> secondList = new List<myobject2>;

                foreach (var c in frstList )
                {
                    secondList.Add( ClaimManager.GetSecondList(c.ID));
                }
```

now my list will contain data like so:

```
frstList: id = 1, id = 2
secondList: id=1 parentid = 1, id=2 parentid=1 and id = 3 parentid = 2
```

I want to count these individually and return the one that has most counts? in above example it should return id=1 from frsList and id1 and id2 from secondList...

tried this but not working

```
var numbers = (from c in frstList where c.Parent.ID == secondList.Select(cl=> cl.ID) select c).Count();
```

can someone please help me either in linq or normal foreach to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. You simply want to return the list with the most items ?

Comment: what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: want to do a count on secondlist and return the greater count...like the example states

Comment: so, just the greater count, not the greater list?

Comment: I don't think that statement in the foreach loop is correct. Please check that. I agree with John and Lostdreamer, the question is not clear.

Comment: You are overwriting secondList everytime your foreach iterates, so I don't understand how you end up with a secondList that has parent IDs 1 AND 2...seems to me you would fetch a secondList that has parentid = 1 and then overwrite it in the next iteration with a list that has parentid = 2, and from your question that doesn't seem to be your intention.

Comment: I have corrected the code above

Comment: So, Sam1, if i understand correctly, you want the result to be a list where the final items are the items that appear most often in each list?

Comment: it is kind of like parent and child and i want to find the parent with most children ... if this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the question it appears that what you want is to determine which of the parent nodes has the most children, and you want the output to be that parent node along with all of its child nodes.

The query is fairly straightforward:

```
var largestGroup = secondList.GroupBy(item => item.ParentID)
  .MaxBy(group => group.Count());  

var mostFrequentParent = largestGroup.Key;
var childrenOfMostFrequentParent = largestGroup.AsEnumerable();
```

We'll just need this helper function, `MaxBy`:

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source
    , Func<TSource, TKey> selector
    , IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    }
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Source was empty");
        }

        TSource maxItem = iterator.Current;
        TKey maxValue = selector(maxItem);

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            TKey nextValue = selector(iterator.Current);
            if (comparer.Compare(nextValue, maxValue) > 0)
            {
                maxValue = nextValue;
                maxItem = iterator.Current;
            }
        }
        return maxItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is kind of like parent and child and i want to find the parent with most children ... if this makes sense

Comment: @Sam1 That's what I guessed you wanted, based on the output values.  Does this do what you want?

Comment: I put the helper in seperate class called helper but i get an error on maxby extension method

Comment: @Sam1 It needs to be in a static class; that's how extension method work.  Also note that, in general, you should provide error messages when reporting a problem on a site like this; I usually won't be able to read your mind to know what you did wrong.

Comment: sorry abt that yea got it now...would you mind explaining what the helper method does because i am new to this..

Comment: It takes in a sequence of items and a selector that computes a value for each item.  It returns the item that's selector resulted in the highest value.  If you use the LINQ method `Max` instead it would return the value that resulted from the function, this instead returns the item that generated that value.  Here you don't want to know how many items are in the group with the largest count, you want to actually get the group with the largest count.  There are other ways of approaching the problem, but they virtually all are more work and less efficient.

Comment: thanks for the explanation..can i return the list by desc order  of the largest group(say for example if i have a date on that second list)

Comment: @Sam1 Sure, just use the `OrderByDecending` method, and order by the date field.